# What is a heavy run?

Tags: vocabulary

> He pushed his trolley around and stared at the barrier. It looked very
>   solid. 
>  He started to walk toward it. People jostled him on their
>   way to platforms nine and ten.  Harry walked more quickly. He was
>   going to smash right into that barrier and then he'd be in trouble --
>   leaning forward on his cart, he broke into **a heavy run** -- the
>   barrier was coming nearer and nearer -- he wouldn't be able to stop --
>   the cart was out of control -- he was a foot away -- he closed his
>   eyes ready for the crash – 
>  It didn't come... 
>  (Harry Potter
>   and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Ron’s mother told Harry how to get onto his platform – all you have to do is walk straight at the barrier between platforms nine and ten. And he walks and then start running toward the barrier. Now, what does ‘a heavy run’ mean?

Comment: A run where you exert a lot of effort; contrast that with _a light jog_. See [Meaning #5 here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/heavy?q=heavy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply means that the run was intense, and a lot of effort was exerted.

**Heavy:** (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heavy)

> (3) of great force, intensity, turbulence, etc.: *a heavy sea*